# The Android SDK location cannot be at the filesystem root. [Mac]

Tags: macos, flutter, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I have try installing Android Studio on my Mac, and I stuck 2 days with this problem, I do each solution found on Stack, and non of them help.

Start with very simple installation, things working ok, but the Android SDK is not installed and each time its open a wizerd to install the SDK.

[Android Studio Setup Wizerd "Missing SDK"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rguGV.png)

Then, clicking next will shows the location

[Selecting Android SDK Location "Default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ7fl.png)

Next,will give me another error says:

"SDK emulator is missing"

[SDK emulator is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uPjI.png)

When click on "New Project", A message says:

"Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted"

[SDK Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV7lm.png)

Finally, its open the Android SDK settings and show the must annoying probelm

"The Android SDK location cannot be at the filesystem root."

[THE PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6uhB.png)

I have tried all the standard solutions like reinstalling, give all the permissions, change the SDK location and resetting to default settings and still not solving the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue, installing Java upfront solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple way, just download the old version for example 2018 version, then update to the latest version

https://developer.android.com/studio/archive